# Calling an Api multiple times C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, .net-core

I am trying to get use the rawg api and get games from their api, i have created the game entity class to parse the data to

```
//game entity
public class Game
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Slug { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Released { get; set; }
        public string Background_Image { get; set; }
        public int Rating { get; set; }
        public int Playtime { get; set; }
    }
```

now i need to get the games from the api, and i made this method

```
public static async Task<List<Game>> ApiRawgGamesRequest()
        {
            var gamesList = new List<Game>();

            for (int i = 1; i < 250; i++)
            {
                using (var msg = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, new Uri($"https://api.rawg.io/api/games?page_size=40&page={i}")))
                using (var response = await _client.SendAsync(msg))
                {
                    response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
                    var gamesResponse = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<Game[]>();
                    gamesList.AddRange(gamesResponse);
                }
            }

            return gamesList;
        }
```

i am trying not to add all the games at once so i used a for loop to continously add the games into a list to potentially reduce the stress.
but i get an error

```
// error
Unhandled exception. System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type 'Domain.Game[]' because the t
ype requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize correctly.
To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) or change the deserialized type so that it is a normal .NET type (e.g. not a primitive type like integer, not a
collection type like an array or List<T>) that can be deserialized from a JSON object. JsonObjectAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON object.
Path 'count', line 1, position 9.)
```

the response from the rawg api looks like this -- the results part is the game data i am trying to collect

```
// api response
{
"count": 454988,
"next": "https://api.rawg.io/api/games?page=2&page_size=40",
"previous": null,
"results": [
{
"id": 3498,
"slug": "grand-theft-auto-v",
"name": "Grand Theft Auto V",
"released": "2013-09-17",
"tba": false,
"background_image": "https://media.rawg.io/media/games/84d/84da2ac3fdfc6507807a1808595afb12.jpg",
"rating": 4.48,
},
{
"id": 4200,
"slug": "portal-2",
"name": "Portal 2",
"released": "2011-04-18",
"tba": false,
"background_image": "https://media.rawg.io/media/games/328/3283617cb7d75d67257fc58339188742.jpg",
"rating": 4.62
}
]
}
```

is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Are you sure this link is an API call? (https://api.rawg.io/api/games?page_size=40&page=)

Comment: oh yeah i forgot it starts from 0, but even when i start from 1 i still get an error

Answer (score 0):

Your exception is resulting from a wrong JSON parsed object.
In your code you are calling:

```
var gamesResponse = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<Game[]>();
```

But the response is the object (from your example JSON):

```
public class GameResponse
    {
        public int Count { get; set; }
        public string Next{ get; set; }
        public string Previous { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<Game> Results { get; set; }
    }
```

If you change it to:

```
var gamesResponse = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<GameResponse>();
```

You will be successful in parsing the response and access the games via:

```
gamesResponse.Results
```

Comment: i had a suspision it was this and you proved right. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

So, you are trying to deserialize only the "results" part of the json, you have to build a class with all the items from the response json.

```
// Root myDeserializedClass = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(myJsonResponse); 
    public class Result    {
        public int id { get; set; } 
        public string slug { get; set; } 
        public string name { get; set; } 
        public string released { get; set; } 
        public bool tba { get; set; } 
        public string background_image { get; set; } 
        public double rating { get; set; } 
    }

    public class Root    {
        public int count { get; set; } 
        public string next { get; set; } 
        public object previous { get; set; } 
        public List<Result> results { get; set; } 
    }
```

You can always use some kind of Json>class generator online, used this for this anwser: https://json2csharp.com/

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of good answers addressing the issue of not having the correct structure. The only thing I am adding here as a good practice and for better control of your variable names are the annotations. Note, DataContract and DataMember are part of the framework but work well with Json.Net even though Json.Net comes with their own set of annotations.

```
    [DataContract]
    public class Payload
    {
        [DataMember(Name = "count")]
        public int Count { get; set; }

        [DataMember(Name = "next")]
        public string Next { get; set; }

        [DataMember(Name = "previous")]
        public string Previous { get; set; }

        [DataMember(Name = "results")]
        public List<GameData> Results { get; set; }
    }

    [DataContract]
    public class GameData
    {
        [DataMember(Name = "id")]
        public long Id { get; set; }

        [DataMember(Name = "slug")]
        public string Slug { get; set; }

        [DataMember(Name = "name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [DataMember(Name = "rating")]
        public float Rating { get; set; }

        [DataMember(Name = "rating_top")]
        public float Rating_top { get; set; }
    }

    public static async Task<IEnumerable<Payload>> GetGameDatasAsync(int page = 1, int pageSize = 40, bool followNext = false, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
    {
        cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();

        string next = $"https://api.rawg.io/api/games?page_size={pageSize}&page={page}";
        var results = new List<Payload>();

        using (var client = new HttpClient())
            do
            {
                var result = await client.GetAsync(next, cancellationToken);

                next = string.Empty;

                if (result.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    var json = await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

                    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(json))
                    {
                        var payload = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Payload>(json);

                        next = payload.Next;

                        results.Add(payload);
                    }
                }

            } while (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(next) && followNext);

        return results;
    }
```